# Как сверить время из бд с текущим?

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть некий телеграмм бот, который будет отправлять сообщения по времени,указаному в бд.
Попытался сверить текущее время со временем из базы - не вышло.
Вот код:

```py
def sending():
    time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    conn = sqlite3.connect("list.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT text FROM 'user_message' where time_={}".format(
            time)
    c.execute(sql)
    text = str(c.fetchone())
    bot.send_message(chat.id, text, reply_markup=keyboard)


print('Начало работы')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sending()
    init_db()
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=2)
```

Выбило **ошибку**.
Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Лучше привыкнуть параметры в sql передавать через связывание/binding (погуглите про sql-инъекции):

```
sql = "SELECT text FROM 'user_message' where time_=?"
c.execute(sql, [time])
```

**UPD.**

Тип `datetime.time` похоже не поддерживается драйвером, попробуйте передать время в формате, [поддерживаемом](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_date_time.htm) `SQLITE3`, например **HH:MM:SS**:

```
time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
...
```

---

Но можно и так (не рекомендую):

```
sql = "SELECT text FROM 'user_message' where time_='{}'".format(time)
c.execute(sql)
```

PS.

Скорее всего и тут `time` придется как выше привести к **HH:MM:SS**

Comment: Все равно выбило ошибку sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: @AlexRey, драйвер поддерживает разные типы питона, но похоже не `time` (`datetime` должен). А какие значения в `time_`? Там именно время или дата-время?